# Implementing a credit card form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to implement the following credit card form... https://github.com/jessepollak/card following the section named `Usage (without jQuery)`. I am implementing it using a text file which has the following code...

```js
var card = new Card({
  form: '#myform',
  container: '#con',
  formSelectors: {
    numberInput: 'input#number'
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="con">
  <form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="number">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessepollak/card/master/dist/card.js">
</script>
```

Unforunately, the result is just that the text item is displayed on the web page. Nothing else. When running the snippet, it shows an error for new Card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using that in code directly blocks from loading script. `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessepollak/card/master/dist/card.js"> </script>`. So Try to

   Replace with  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/card/2.5.4/card.min.js"></script>`
2. You have to pass the respective fields with **formSelectors**
   `numberInput: 'input#number'` this was wrong way to with selection.
3. Still you will get the error in console so need to pass the remaining elements with that.

#### Try below code snippet

```js
var card = new Card({
    form: '#myform',
    container: '#con',
    formSelectors: {
        numberInput: 'input[name="number"]',
        expiryInput: 'input[name="expiry"]',
        cvcInput: 'input[name="cvc"]',
        nameInput: 'input[name="name"]'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/card/2.5.4/card.min.js"></script>

<div id="con">
    <form id="myform">
        <input placeholder="Card Number" type="text" name="number">
        <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="name">
        <input placeholder="CSV" type="text" name="cvc">
        <input placeholder="Expiry" type="text" name="expiry">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh for prompt reply. There are some things I need to understand if you do not mind. 1- What prevents card.js from being uploaded? P.S, I tried referencing card.js locally after downloading it.
2- I am not sure if the file does not get uploaded, because I can see it in the console. 
3- I noticed that you did not reference card.js at the end of the body as the guide says. How does it work?
4- Can I use the default value of the selectors without writing them? 
5- I am going to attach my text file after using your method. It did not work either.

Comment: Here's an image that shows that the file is uploaded successfully.
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1VmDdszirzbC9AvzfgLnW2wZ2g6bKXeBWAEzC6JBnT6k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's my text file looks like...

Comment: ```<body>
<div id="con">
<form id="myform">
<input placeholder="Card Number" type="text" name="number">
<input placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="name">
<input placeholder="CSV" type="text" name="cvc">
<input placeholder="Expiry" type="text" name="expiry">
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/card/2.5.4/card.min.js">
var card = new Card({form: '#myform',container: '#con',formSelectors: {numberInput: 'input[name="number"]',expiryInput: 'input[name="expiry"]',
cvcInput: 'input[name="cvc"]',nameInput: 'input[name="name"]'}});
</script>
</body>```

Comment: @Eslam you have added script in external script tag. Try this [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maheshmthorat/rxm8h6te/)

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh. It worked when I set the "src" attribute in it's own tag and added another script tag with the code "var card = new Card.......".

Comment: Welcome @Eslam you can accept the answer and upvote for future reference for community.